# Heap memory pointer lost from pointer field inside a structure

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, threadpool

I am trying to implement a thread pool in C using POSIX threads library. In the function where thread pool is initialized, dynamic memory allocation is performed for both **thpool** and field **jobqueue** but when I try to access jobqueue field from another function the pointer value is **NULL**. Here is my code:

*threadpool.h*

```
#include <pthread.h>

typedef void *(*funcptr) (void *);

typedef enum JOBSTATUS
{
    COMPLETED,
    RUNNING,
    PENDING
} jobstatus;

typedef struct _job
{
    funcptr f;
    void *args;
} job;

typedef struct _thpool
{
    job *jobqueue;
    int jobquesize;
    int jobtail;
    int jobhead;
    int occupiedjobs;

    pthread_t *threadqueue;
    int nofthreads;
    int threadsOccupied;
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;
    pthread_cond_t q_notempty;
    pthread_cond_t q_empty;
} thpool;

thpool *createWorkers(int numofthreads, int nofjobs);
```

*threadpool.c*

```
#include "threadpool.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *primetest(void *args)
{
    int *k = (int *)args;
    int i, counter;
    for (i = 0; i <= *k; i++)
    {
        if (*k % i == 0)
            counter++;
    }
    return counter >= 3 ? (void *)0 : (void *)1;
}

void *dothreadWork(void *args)
{
    thpool *thp = (thpool *)args;
    funcptr f;
    void *arg;
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(thp->mtx));
        while (thp->occupiedjobs == 0 /*&& thp->jobtail==thp->jobhead */ )
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&thp->q_notempty, &thp->mtx);
        }
        f = thp->jobqueue[thp->jobhead].f;
        arg = thp->jobqueue[thp->jobhead].args;
        --thp->occupiedjobs;
        //if(thp->jobquesize==0)
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(thp->mtx));
        f(arg);
    }
}

thpool *createWorkers(int numofthreads, int nofjobs)
{
    int i;
    thpool *thp = (thpool *)malloc(sizeof(thpool));
    if (thp == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    thp->jobqueue = (job *)malloc(sizeof(job) * nofjobs);
    if (thp->jobqueue = NULL)
    {
        free(thp);
        return NULL;
    }
    thp->threadqueue = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numofthreads);
    if (thp->threadqueue == NULL)
    {
        free(thp->jobqueue);
        free(thp);
        return NULL;
    }
    pthread_mutex_init(&thp->mtx, 0);
    pthread_cond_init(&thp->q_notempty, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&thp->q_empty, NULL);
    thp->jobquesize = nofjobs;
    thp->jobtail = thp->jobhead = 0;
    thp->occupiedjobs = 0;
    thp->threadsOccupied = 0;
    thp->nofthreads = numofthreads;
    for (i = 0; i < numofthreads; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&(thp->threadqueue[i]), NULL, dothreadWork, thp) > 0)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return thp;
}
void jobqueuepush(thpool **thp, funcptr f, void *args)
{
    printf("Jobqueue Push!");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&((*thp)->mtx));
    if ((*thp)->jobquesize == (*thp)->occupiedjobs)
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&((*thp)->mtx));
        return;
    }
    if ((*thp)->jobqueue == NULL)   // The problem is here
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&((*thp)->mtx));
        printf("Problem in memory allocation\n");
        return;
    }
    //(*thp)->jobqueue[(*thp)->jobtail].f = f;
    //(*thp)->jobqueue[(*thp)->jobtail].args = args;
    //++(*thp)->occupiedjobs;
    (*thp)->jobtail = ((*thp)->jobtail + 1) % ((*thp)->jobquesize);
    if ((*thp)->occupiedjobs == 1)
        pthread_cond_signal(&((*thp)->q_notempty));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&((*thp)->mtx));

}

int main(int argc, void *argv[])
{
    thpool *p = createWorkers(4, 2);

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        int k = 4;
        jobqueuepush(&p, primetest, &k);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

My question is why even if we allocate dynamically the memory in heap this allocation pointer for **jobqueue** field of **struct thpool** does not seem to remain alive although for **thpool** that is returned from function **createWorkers** we still have it? Something I miss here for sure.

Comment: Please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Debugging is made much easier if you don't write large parts of code between testing. Do testing more often, after writing only small pieces of code.

Comment: You miss indentation for sure.

Comment: `remain alive` how did you diagnosed it? what do you mean by that? I like this design, but there is still some work to do. Basically this is just consumer-producer problem with a single producer. I believe when `//(*thp)->jobqueue[(*thp)->jobtail].f = f;` is commented out, you call null in worker thread.

Comment: Inside the main function when createWorkers function returned I printed out the pointer, it was the same than the one allocated inside createWorkers function. I suppose that heap allocated for the process will be still there till the process ends, am I right? Also I did not want to use global variables to do my job here.

Comment: `am I right?` - The pointer will be valid until program terminates or calls `free` on the pointer. | Still `not seem to remain alive` - how did you diagnosed it? How do you detect it? Can you post the `printf` you used? | `createWorkers function returned I printed out the pointer, it was the same than the one allocated inside createWorkers function` - when you return a pointer (value) it will stay the same. The `return` statement will not change pointer value. Don't know how you could diagnose that the memory "is not alive".

Comment: I have used the following printout commands inside main function: `printf("pointer:%p\n",p); printf("jobs size:%d\n",p->jobquesize); printf("jobs queue pointer:%p\n",p->jobqueue);` For **jobqueusize** I still get the value **2** as the argument value passed on **createWorkers** function. For heap memory I think that the pointer should be still remained there. Here somehow the **jobqueue** pointer field has been nullified and I want to understand why.

Comment: Is the division by zero in `primetest` intentional? And the use of uninitialized `counter`?

Comment: @Ian: This has been slipped through. For _i_ it should be **1** and for **counter** it should be **0**

Comment: `if (thp->jobqueue = NULL)` is the problem.

Comment: @Ian: If you are checking things late at night, you miss such typo errors! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`if (thp->jobqueue = NULL)` is the problem.
                    – Ian Abbott